# fuslogvw -- could not load file or assembly on server

Tags: dll, dynamics-ax-2012, server, aif, fuslogvw

I'm trying to invoke an Dynamics AX AIF inbound port (service) on a development server from my laptop using wcfTestClient. Because customErrors = Off, I can see the error message and it says it couldn't load an assembly.

I've set fuslogVw on the client and server. The client shows me a bunch of DLLs, but not the one that is throwing teh error.

I've set fusLogvw on the server as well, but it doesn't log anything.

How can I capture the DLL load details on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: When you run fuslogvw on the server, it doesn't log anything?  Have you tried just clicking "refresh"?  Maybe log into the server as the AOS service account.

Comment: Try to enable error output at server. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760943/ax-2012-r3-cu8-system-servicemodel-faultexception-an-error-occurred/30761198#30761198